# Form Control in form array is undefined

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I am new in angular and I'm having problem with my newly added form control. This formcontrol is not visible in the user. The "result" works perfectly but my newly added "include" produce UNDEFINED result when I do the

```
this.ATests.at(index).patchValue({include: 1});
alert(this.ATests.controls[index].value.include);
```

in my itsMine.component.ts. Anyway, it is the checkbox event that do this, please see my codes below for more details. Thank You In Advance good people.

---

This is my **itsMine.model.ts**:

```
export class ATbl {
    result: string;
    include: number;
  constructor (ATblForm){
      this.result=ATblForm.result || '';
      this.include=AtblForm.include || '';
  }
}
```

---

This is my **itsMine.component.html**:

```
<form [formGroup]="AFormGroup">
    <div formArrayName="ATests" >
        <div fxlayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center" *ngFor="let test of ATests.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
            <mat-checkbox [id]="'chkInclude_' + i"
                      (click)="setIncludeValue(i,$event)">
            </mat-checkbox>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

---

This is my **itsMine.component.ts**:

```
AFormGroup : FormGroup;

constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder
){
    this.AFormGroup = this.fb.group({
        ATests: this.fb.array([])
    });
}

setIncludeValue(index,event) {
    this.ATests.at(index).patchValue({include: 1});
    alert(this.ATests.controls[index].value.include);
}
```

Am I missing something? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: can you do a "console.log(this.ATests.controls[index].value)" just before the alert? What is the value after you call patchValue? I know it should be {include: 1} but for some reason it is not

Comment: another hint for more answers: you could provide an example on stackblitz.com, so other users can more quickly find the solution to your question

Comment: @TobiasGassmann I did the console.log(this.ATests.controls[index].value) and the include didn't appear. Hmm...

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are missing the `ATests` getter. You have to push something `FormGroup` or `FormControl` in your `FormArray`. Then you can write something like

```
this.ATests.at(index).patchValue({include: 1});
```

The statement in alert is also wrong.

Here is a **example** of how you can initiate a form with `FormArray` the patch some value and get the data.

```
AFormGroup : FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){
    this.AFormGroup = this.fb.group({
        ATests: this.fb.array([])
    });
    this.setIncludeControl();
    this.setIncludeValue(0,12);
}

get ATests() {
    return this.AFormGroup.get('ATests') as FormArray;
}

setIncludeControl() {
    this.ATests.push(
        this.fb.group({
            include: []
        })
    );
}

setIncludeValue(index, value) {
    this.ATests.at(index).patchValue({include: value});
    console.log(this.ATests.at(index).get('include').value);
}
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e6rhvw) you can find the full demo.

Comment: for this question.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57831605/display-checkbox-based-on-object-response-angular, Im trying, use your solution..https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4b6car?file=src%2Fapp%2Finquiry-response%2Finquiry-response.component.ts..but I got error in my ide `this.receivedSummons.map is not a function`..but works well on stackblitz, any idea ?