# display checkbox based on object response Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, checkbox, angular-reactive-forms

I want to create dynamic `checkbox` based on object response,It should create multiple `checkbox` based on this response:

**test.json**

```
[  
  {  
   "header":{  
      "serviceId":"inquiry-service",
      "productCode":"JPJXXX",
      "transactionId":"cfad2ac7c16XXX"
   },
   "data":{  
      "items":[  
         {  
            "offenceType4":"",
            "permSpeed":"110",
            "actSpeed":"123",
            "itemAttributes":{  
               "attribute5":"",
               "attribute4":"VQ3XXX",
               "attribute7":"14.21.00",
               "attribute6":"2018-03-22",
               "attribute1":"XXXXX",
               "attribute3":"XXXXXX",
               "attribute2":"XXXXXX"
            },
            "offenceLoc":"XXXXXX",
            "itemNo":"1",
            "summonDate":"2018-04-02",
            "distCode":"XXXXXX",
            "summonType":"2",
            "hbtlOffndr":"N",
            "itemAmount":15000,
            "itemAttributesCount":7,
            "summonAmt":"150.00",
            "offenceType1":"48",
            "offenceCode1":"XXXXXX",
            "offenceType2":"",
            "offenceCode2":"",
            "offenceType3":"",
            "category":"4",
            "offenceCode3":"",
            "offenceCode4":"",
            "respCode":"XXXXXX"
         },
         {  
            "offenceType4":"",
            "permSpeed":"110",
            "actSpeed":"123",
            "itemAttributes":{  
               "attribute5":"",
               "attribute4":"XXXXXX",
               "attribute7":"10.13.31",
               "attribute6":"2018-06-16",
               "attribute1":"XXXXXX",
               "attribute3":"XXXXXX",
               "attribute2":"XXXXXX"
            },
            "offenceLoc":"XXXXXX",
            "itemNo":"2",
            "summonDate":"2018-07-23",
            "distCode":"XXXXXX",
            "summonType":"2",
            "hbtlOffndr":"N",
            "itemAmount":15000,
            "itemAttributesCount":7,
            "summonAmt":"150.00",
            "offenceType1":"48",
            "offenceCode1":"XXXXXX",
            "offenceType2":"",
            "offenceCode2":"",
            "offenceType3":"",
            "category":"4",
            "offenceCode3":"",
            "offenceCode4":"",
            "respCode":"XXXXXX"
         }
      ],
      "status":{  
         "code":"",
         "message":""
      },
      "additionalProperties":{  
         "serviceFee":0,
         "total":0,
         "deliveryFee":0,
         "foreignCardSurcharge":0,
         "serviceFeeTax":0,
         "subTotal":0,
         "deliveryFeeTax":0
      },
      "metadata":{  
         "count":2
      }
   },
   "status":{  
      "code":"200",
      "message":"OK"
   }
}
]
```

what I want is checkbox to be created based on `data.items` if `items` consist of 2 arrays, it should create 2 `checkboxes`.then selected checkboxes can be submit and it need `header.transactionId`, if I filter and only got `data.items` how could I add `header.transactionId` when submit.

I had created demo [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-suoez9?file=src%2Fapp%2Finquiry-response%2Finquiry-response.component.ts) and this is what I had tried:

**Ts File**

```
  receivedSummons: SummonModel[];
  selectedSummon: string;
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private inquiryStore: InquiryStoreService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      receivedSummons: new FormArray([], minSelectedCheckboxes(1))
    });
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getReceivedSummons();
  }

  getReceivedSummons() {
      this.inquiryStore.summons$.subscribe(receivedSummons => {
      this.receivedSummons = receivedSummons;
      this.addCheckboxes();
    })
  }

  addCheckboxes() {
    this.receivedSummons.map((i) => {
      const control = new FormControl;
      (this.form.controls.receivedSummons as FormArray).push(control);
    });
  }

  submitSelectedCheckboxes() {
    this.selectedSummon = this.form.value.receivedSummons
      .map((v, i) => (v ? this.receivedSummons[i] : null))
      .filter(v => v !== null);
      console.log(this.selectedSummon)
  }

}
```

**Html File**

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submitSelectedCheckboxes()">
  <label formArrayName="receivedSummons" *ngFor="let summon of form.controls.receivedSummons.controls; let i = index">
    <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i">
  </label>
  <div *ngIf="!form.valid">At least one order must be selected</div>
  <br>
  <button [disabled]="!form.valid">submit</button>
</form>
```

I could use some guidance and suggestion on how to solve this.

Comment: I don't see the code you have posted in your StackBlitz.

Comment: @nash11 but the code still there under inquiry-response folder

Comment: I'm not very clear on what you're trying to achieve here. In your demo, you have an input but no matter what you type in it, as long as it has any 4 numbers you can submit and you're just displaying the checkboxes. What exactly do you want the `value` of your checkbox to be?

Comment: after I put 4 number, then I got reponse obj, using behaviourSubject I send it to inquiry response, based on response obj `data.items` , I want to bind checkboxes, if `data.items` length = 2, there will be a 2 checkboxes

Comment: also I also need `header.transactionId` with checkboxes to send to another component

Comment: Yes, I got that but I'm not very clear on what the value of the checkbox should be. Like for example, if you select a checkbox, other than `header.transactionId`, what other data should be passed? Otherwise, you have only one `transactionId` so how will you differentiate between the two checkboxes?

Comment: my use case like summon, if user have 2 summons under 1 `transactionId`,  `data.items` is number of summon and what difference it is `itemNo` in `data.items`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199122/discussion-between-hafizi-and-nash11).

Answer (score -2):

First of all when using `FormBuilder` try not to instantiate `FormControl` or `FormArray` directly. Instead use `FormBuilder` to do so.

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    receivedSummons: this.formBuilder.array([])
});
```

As your `response` is an `array` you can get multiple `receivedSummons` which can contain multiple `data.items`. You need a different form structure to solve your issue.

Your `addCheckboxes` function might look like this.

```
addCheckboxes() {
    this.formReceivedSummons.setValue([]);
    this.receivedSummons.map(x => {
        const group = this.formBuilder.group({
            header: [x.header.transactionId],
            items: this.formBuilder.array([], [minSelectedCheckboxes(1)])
        });
        x.data.items.map(y => {
            (group.get('items') as FormArray).push(this.formBuilder.group({
                name: [y.itemNo],
                isChecked: ['']
            }));
        });
        this.formReceivedSummons.push(group);
    });
}
```

Also change the `html` file accordingly.

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submitSelectedCheckboxes()">
    <ng-container formArrayName="receivedSummons" *ngFor="let summon of formReceivedSummons.controls; let i = index">
        <ng-container [formGroup]="summon">
            <p>{{summon.value.header}}</p>
            <ng-container formArrayName="items" *ngFor="let item of formReceivedSummonsItems(i).controls; let j = index">
                <ng-container [formGroup]="item">
                    <input type="checkbox" formControlName="isChecked"> {{item.value.name}}
                </ng-container>
            </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
        <div *ngIf="!summon.valid">At least one order must be selected</div>
    </ng-container>
    <br>
    <button [disabled]="!form.valid">submit</button>
</form>
```

Here 2 getters were used to get the `receivedSummons` and `items` `FormArray`

```
get formReceivedSummons() {
    return this.form.get('receivedSummons') as FormArray;
}

formReceivedSummonsItems(i: number) {
    return (this.formReceivedSummons.controls[i].get('items')) as FormArray;
}
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4b6car) you can find the full demo.